# Java 8 list to existing map

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I have a map `Map<Id,Map<Obj1,Obj2>> existingMap and List<Obj1> list`;
I need to add list values to map as key and new Map as value.

I tried to do something like:

```
existingMap.putAll(list.stream().map(x->x.getId()).collect(
Collectors.toMap(x, x -> Map<Obj1,Obj2>::new);
```

How should I write it? And how can use parameterized constructor against default?

Comment: Map is an interface. You can't use new on an interface. Choose a concrete Map implementation (HashMap for example)

Comment: That said, a good old for loop would be more readable here, IMO

Comment: What if the list contains an element that's an existing key in the map? Should you fail? Clobber the old value? Leave the current entry alone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
list.forEach(e -> existingMap.put(e.getId(), new HashMap<>()));
```

Still uses functional Java 8 features, same effect.

`for`-loop equivalent:

```
for(Id id : list)
    existingMap.put(id.getId(), new HashMap<>());
```

Problems with your code:

- `Map` is an interface, and can't be instantiated. Use a concrete implementation like `HashMap` or `TreeMap` for example.
- `Collectors#toMap` accepts *two* `Function`s. If you want to use your format, you'd need:

  ```
  Collectors.toMap(x -> x, HashMap::new)
  ```

  Notice the lambda `x -> x` instead of simply `x`.

  Edit: Of course, you can use `Function.identity()`, which is more verbose, instead of `x -> x`, but depending on your needs this *may* be more expressive.

Comment: Thank you! It's so simple! I use HashMap of course. Just wrote question quickly.

Answer (score 2):

One more way can be transformation applying collector:

```
List<Id> list = ...
Map<Id, Map<Obj1, Obj2>> extension = list.stream().collect(
        toMap(
                identity(),
                value -> new HashMap<Obj1, Obj2>()
        )
);

existingMap.putAll(extension);
```

you have to add the following imports to make it work:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```